# I disabled a module and my website turns into code

Tags: 5

I am working on an old Drupal website. I disabled the Electric Embers subscribe module - to get rid of a newsletter subscription option to a dead list.    Previously my website was in off-line mode, but otherwise worked.    Now the website looks like pure text or code.

www.rachel.org

I checked the database and the ee-subscribe module is still enabled.

Unfortunately I didn't make a backup before turning off this module.  However, I've never seen turning off a module cause so much havoc.

I currently cannot use my admin log in or do anything directly through drupal.

**Update**
When does Drupal 5 change the filename field in the system table? The problem occurs when it sets the "filename" field to "modulename.info" (or .install or .js) for 10-20 modules.  I can manually set it to "modulename.module" but the fix only lasts an hour or so.

I don't think that cron is running as there are no cron jobs scheduled and I do not use poormanscron.  However I don't know how to test this.

Comment: Anything in the server logs?

Comment: If you still have a valid session cookie you can try going to www.rachel.org/update.php and see if that helps.  Do you have drush installed?

Comment: Before you do anything else, back up your site. The 'code' being displayed is actually the content of your `.info` files. These files are read to support the enabling and disabling of modules. Otherwise everything the bootstrap requires is in the system table. My hunch is that the disabling of your module did not complete for some reason and you are hung up mid-process. I would try disabling the module in the database.

Comment: I don't see anything in error_log (last updated 11 months ago), or watchdog table (probably emptied by cron - only 25 rows).

I tried disabling the module in the database, but that didn't work. 

Backup is underway.

Comment: Can I reset or stop the drupal "add"/"remove" module process?

Comment: Somebody turned off error logging!    
New error: [08-Jul-2013 20:17:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_access() in /home/rachelor/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 1384

Comment: In the system table the filename for the users module is: "modules/user/user.info".  Should it be "modules/user/user.module"?

There is a mixture of filename values ending in .module, .info, and .install.  What is this used for?

Comment: So I set that filename to "modules/user/user.module" and now I get an error:  
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function filter_xss_admin() in /home/rachelor/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 348

Should all of my system.filename values where status=1 have .module endings?

Comment: Could it be a problem with using PHP 5?  I know drupal 5 doesn't support it and the website is using PHP 5.3.15.

Note: this is an old installation of Drupal that I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Drush if you have installed it.

```
> drush dis your_module_name
> drush cc all
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, although it appears your running Drupal 5.x, no longer supported nor secure. I forget why I saw it last time, but it shouldn't be hard to set straight. As [Chris Rockwell](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7595/chris-rockwell) indicates, check your server logs to see if there's any permissions related errors (i.e., can not access filex.php) I don't know what kind of host your own but ensure your permissions are correct. Here's *the* essential drupal page for this: https://drupal.org/node/244924

This page might nail it for you? https://drupal.org/node/172729

Comment: Where are the server logs?  I've looked at watchdog and didn't find anything (possibly it was pruned by cron). I don't see anything in public_html (the error_log hasn't been updated in 11 months old).

Comment: I changed it and settings.php now has 0644 permissions (but this hasn't helped) .  They were 0444 when I tried to disable the module.

Comment: While I'd love to help, if this is Drupal 5, then I must excuse myself. I wouldn't run something as vulnerable as a public-facing application stack beyond it's end-of-life.

Comment: Well I don't know if I can upgrade it while it has this problem.

Comment: But I might try upgrading as a way of fixing it.

Comment: Roughly speaking my guidance would be to restore the site to a previous working state from backup and perform the upgrade. Granted, major updates are non-trivial and you should consider moving to D7. The other option is to refactor the site fresh in D7, which offers it's own advantages.

Comment: Unfortunately I disabled the module before making a backup. I didn't think it'd be an issue.  The previous tech person didn't setup automated backups.

Comment: That's a world of compromise. There's always the "Wayback Machine" which I've used for clients and friends in your predicament: http://web.archive.org/web/20080117152645/http://skrinakcreative.com/

Answer (score 0):

I went through the system table and changed all the filename values for modules to have .module extensions.  So of the filenames had been set to .info, .install, or .js extensions.

Now the "website is offline" message appears properly and the admin user can login.

I still haven't figured out what caused the problem in the first place.  I'd like to be able to install/uninstall modules without problems.

Comment: This fix only worked for a short time. And then the system table values for filename were set back to ".info", ".install", and ".js" for some of the modules.  I'm guessing that the cron job is doing this.

Comment: I changed the update_status_last value in the variables table to far in the future -- and now this fix appears to be holding.  However, I still have no clue what the original cause is and I cannot add/remove modules or upgrade to Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not set 0 (zero) for status field for any core modules. Because what you see on the page is all the .info file data. This means, Drupal does not work beyond reading .info file details. Also, check custom modules, if any, for debug code. Check also 'system' module.